# Binding variables in an anonymous function inside a for each loop

Tags: actionscript-3

The following code will add only the last Widget in the loop to *all* the listener functions. All the functions will call toggleShow() on the last object.

Why does this happen, and is there a way to get each Widget object to be referenced in the corresponding function?

```
for each (var w:Widget in workspace.getWidgetList()) {
    var widgetShow:NativeMenuItem = menu.addItem(new NativeMenuItem("Show " + w.title)); 
    widgetShow.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, function():void {
        w.toggleShow();
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a function, this happens because the loop runs to the end and w becomes the last element in that list so when the anonymous function is called it always uses the last element :

```
for each (var w:Widget in workspace.getWidgetList()) {
   addMenuItem(w);
}

function addMenuItem(w:Widget):void
{
    var widgetShow:NativeMenuItem = menu.addItem(new NativeMenuItem("Show " + w.title)); 
    widgetShow.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, function():void {
        w.toggleShow();
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I still don't understand it fully though. It also worked to define an anonymous function and assign it to a variable before the loop.